# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to0} \left(\cos x\right)^{\cot^2 x}$

Tags: limits

> Find $$\lim_{x\to0} \left(\cos x\right)^{\cot^2 x}$$

Sadly, I'm stuck trying to solve this. I'm assuming I have to use L'Hopital's rule, but I don't see how I can. It isn't homework or anything, just revising limits.

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using the rule $u^v = \exp( v \log u)$?

Comment: Is it $\lim_{x\to 0} (\cos x)^{\cot(x^2)}$ or $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x^{\cot(x^2)})$ or something else?

Comment: (cos(x)) ^ ((cosx)^2) @ThomasAndrews

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Stefanie Could you clarify whether you mean cosine or cotangent? Compare your comment with the title.

Comment: @user49640 shoot, sorry about that. the first is cos, the second is cot. I should totally learn MathJax, haha

Comment: We can use WolframAlpha and see that [the answer is $\frac 1{\sqrt{e}}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+0+(cos+x)%5E(cot%5E2+x))

Comment: Sonnhard Graubner has written a hint. It's the same idea that was in my comment above. Would you like to try and take it from there? You can edit your calculations into your question and then we can comment.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Unfortunately, it is $\cot 0$, which is not $1$.

Comment: You can set $y=\cot^2x$ and you get that $\cos^2 x = \frac{y}{y+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: your limit is $$e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(cos(x))}{\tan(x)^2}}$$ and use L'Hopital

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you you arrived at the hint?

Comment: @Stefanie It's based on what I wrote in my comment above.

Comment: @Stefanie This is a common trick for then you have a complicated function as an exponent. Another way to look at this is this: Suppose the limit is $L$, so $\lim_{x\to0} \left(\cos x\right)^{\cot^2 x}=L$. Now take $\ln$ of both sides, $\ln(\lim_{x\to0} \left(\cos x\right)^{\cot^2 x}) = \ln L$. You can bring the limit on the outside of the $\ln$, and solve the limit. You should get $\ln ( \frac {1}{\sqrt e}) = \ln L$. Make each side an exponent of $e$, and you get $L = \dfrac {1}{\sqrt e}$